# APPDATA environment variable in Jenkins for NPM

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I run a windows jenkins agent as a scheduled task with an admin user as in [the jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Launch+Java+Web+Start+slave+agent+via+Windows+Scheduler)

If I start the scheduled task at bootup and I run a simple build to print all the environment variables I can see that some like `APPDATA` are missing.

NPM depends on this variable as I can see in the npmrc so build fails

```
prefix=${APPDATA}\npm
```

If I start the scheduled task from the UI after the user logs in then those variables are available for the build.

What's the right way to handle this?

Comment: You can setup a scheduled job on `jenkins`, right ?

Comment: yes @Malice. To simplify test I created a simple pipeline job where I do a SET to retrieve all the environment variables available-

Comment: So what exactly is the problem ? The variables not defined during boot up ?

Comment: @Malice if the agent is started with server boot user variables are not available. If started with user session open then yes.